# List of tuples not sorted numerically in python

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

When I sort my list of tuples by descending with numerical values with this function :

```
data.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[1], reverse=True)
```

I have this order of tuples in my list :

```
data = [("a", 8001),
        ("b", 8000),
        ("c", 8),
        ("d", 10)]
```

It's sorted by alphabet and not numerical. 8 > 10 because 8 is greater than first letter of 10 which is 1.

How can I sort my list of tuples by numerical descending order ?

Comment: Your code looks fine? You check the order of `data` after sorting in place to check it worked yes?

Comment: Are you sure you have integers there, and not the strings "8001", "8000", "8", and "10"?  Strings are not integers, and they sort differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original code works just fine

```
>>> data = [("a", 8001),
...         ("b", 8000),
...         ("c", 8),
...         ("d", 10)]
>>>
>>> data
[('a', 8001), ('b', 8000), ('c', 8), ('d', 10)]
>>> data.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[1], reverse=True)
>>>
>>> data
[('a', 8001), ('b', 8000), ('d', 10), ('c', 8)]
```